# VM Storage and Memory Allocation ratio

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, performance

I have a VM server, The usage for this server is for PHP web server. 
My storage is 6.5GB, and my RAM 12gb. 
Is this setting good for performance?
My concern is the swap memory.

Any advice for VM expert? what is the formula for the ratio?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no formula for the ratio. It would depend on your actual load and what you're doing.

Comment: I actually having occasionally slow performance. I have no idea where to find the issue. So my mind prompt out it might be memory swap. So I need some justification talk to my boss to increase it. It might be the issue or not. So I ask from here looking for expert for helping.

Comment: Well did you monitor your RAM/swap usage in order to check whenever they correlate with the slow down?